# How can I monitor the services in the mesh?

Tags: ignite

I deployed some service in the services mesh. Does have some tool to monitor these services?

Such as service status,call times...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Ignite don't seem to have any statistics on services, you will need to roll your own.